# footer floating way out of position on some pages

Tags: css, html, footer

[My blog's](http://speechnotrecognised.blogspot.com) footer is fine on post pages, but on the home page, it literally places itself in a different element (the main-wrapper).

I was able to ascertain this using Chrome's Developer Tools.

I am beginning to think there is something seriously wrong with my html as I had strange positional issues with my sidebar also.

CSS:

```
#footer {
  width:1100px;
  height:26pt;
  padding:10px;
  margin:20px auto 0px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size:12pt;
  text-align: center;
  background:#ffffff;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
  line-height:1.4em;
  clear:both;
  display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <body>





  <div id='outer-wrapper'>


   <div id='content-wrapper'>

      <div id='crosscol-wrapper' style='text-align:center'>
        <b:section class='crosscol' id='crosscol'/>
      </div>

 <div id='sidebar-wrapper'>
        <b:section class='sidebar' id='sidebar' preferred='yes'>

<b:widget id='HTML5' locked='false' title='MRS SPEECH&apos;S RECIPE OF THE WEEK' type='HTML'>
<b:includable id='main'>

  <div class='widget-content'>
    <data:content/>
  </div>

  <b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:includable>
</b:widget>
</b:section>
      </div>


      <div id='main-wrapper'>
        <b:section class='main' id='main' showaddelement='no'>
<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>
<b:includable id='nextprev'>



      <div class='clear'>&#160;</div>
  <div class='blog-pager' id='blog-pager'>
    <b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
      <span id='blog-pager-newer-link'>
      <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'><img src='http://i1252.photobucket.com/albums/hh569/speechnotrecognised/9f703b71.png'/></a>
      </span>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>


      <span id='blog-pager-older-link'>
      <a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'><img src='http://i1252.photobucket.com/albums/hh569/speechnotrecognised/54059f04.png'/></a>
      </span>
    </b:if>


    <b:if cond='data:mobileLinkUrl'>
      <div class='blog-mobile-link'>
        <a expr:href='data:mobileLinkUrl'><data:mobileLinkMsg/></a>
      </div>
    </b:if>

  </div>
  <div class='clear'/>
</b:includable>



<b:includable id='mobile-main' var='top'>
    <!-- posts -->


<b:includable id='post' var='post'>






<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>

  <div class='post1 hentry'>

    <a expr:name='data:post.id'/>


    <div class='post1-header'>

<div class='post1-header-line'>

    <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
      <h3 class='post1-title entry1-title'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.link'>
        <a expr:href='data:post.link'><data:post.title/></a>
      <b:else/>
        <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
          <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:post.url'>
            <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
          <b:else/>
            <data:post.title/>
          </b:if>
        <b:else/>
          <data:post.title/>
        </b:if>
      </b:if>
      </h3>

    </b:if>

<div class='comments1'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'><b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'><center><a class='comment-link' expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' expr:onclick='data:post.addCommentOnclick'>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 0'>0</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 1'>1</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments &gt; 1'><data:post.numComments/></b:if></a></center>
            </b:if>
          </b:if>

</div>
</div>


<div class='post1-header-line'>

<div class='date1-header'>
<b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart'>   
        <b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
          <data:post.dateHeader/>

        </b:if>

        </b:if>

</div>
<span style='margin:0 15px 0 15px;  float:left;'>/</span>
<div class='post1-labels'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
          <data:postLabelsLabel/>
          <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
            <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a><b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>,</b:if>
          </b:loop>
        </b:if>
      </div>

    </div>

    </div>


    <div class='post1-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id'>

<div class='post1-header-line'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'> <iframe allowTransparency='true' expr:src='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot; + data:post.canonicalUrl + &quot;&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21&quot;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;'/> </b:if>

<a class='twitter-share-button' data-count='standard' data-lang='en' data-via='' expr:data-text='data:post.title' expr:data-url='data:post.url' href='http://twitter.com/share' rel='nofollow'>Tweet</a>

    </div>


<script src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' type='text/javascript'>

</script>


<data:post.body/>

<b:if cond='data:post.hasJumpLink'>
      <div class='jump-link'>
        <a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' expr:title='data:post.title'><img src='http://i1252.photobucket.com/albums/hh569/speechnotrecognised/2395f7fb.png'/></a>
      </div>
    </b:if>

<!-- Related Posts with Thumbnails Code Start-->
<!-- remove --><b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div id='related-posts'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>
</b:if>
<script expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=related_results_labels_thumbs&amp;max-results=6&quot;' type='text/javascript'/></b:loop>
<script type='text/javascript'>
removeRelatedDuplicates_thumbs();
printRelatedLabels_thumbs(&quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;);
</script>
</div><div style='clear:both'/>
<!-- remove --></b:if>
<!-- Related Posts with Thumbnails Code End-->



    </div>



    <div class='post1-footer'>


    <div class='post1-footer-line post1-footer-line-1'>






      </div>

      <div class='post1-footer-line post1-footer-line-2'> </div>

      <div class='post1-footer-line post1-footer-line-3'/>
    </div>
  </div>



<b:else/>







  <div class='post hentry' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/BlogPosting'>
    <a expr:name='data:post.id'/>
    <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
      <h3 class='post-title entry-title' itemprop='name'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.link'>
        <a expr:href='data:post.link'><data:post.title/></a>
      <b:else/>
        <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
          <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:post.url'>
            <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
          <b:else/>
            <data:post.title/>
          </b:if>
        <b:else/>
          <data:post.title/>
        </b:if>
      </b:if>
      </h3>
    </b:if>

    <div class='post-header'>
    <div class='post-header-line-1'/>
    </div>

    <div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id' itemprop='articleBody'>
      <data:post.body/>
    </div>

    <div class='post-footer'>


      <div class='jump-link'>
        <a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' expr:title='data:post.title'><img src='http://i1252.photobucket.com/albums/hh569/speechnotrecognised/2395f7fb.png'/></a>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>

  </b:if>




</b:includable>
<b:includable id='comment_picker' var='post'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.commentSource == 1'>
    <b:include data='post' name='iframe_comments'/>
  <b:else/>
    <b:if cond='data:post.showThreadedComments'>
      <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
    <b:else/>
      <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
    </b:if>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='status-message'>
  <b:if cond='data:navMessage'>
  <div class='status-msg-wrap'>
    <div class='status-msg-body'>
      <data:navMessage/>
    </div>
        <div class='status-msg-hidden'><data:navMessage/></div>
      </div>
  <div style='clear: both;'/>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='comment-form' var='post'>
  <div class='comment-form'>
    <a name='comment-form'/>
    <b:if cond='data:mobile'>
      <h4 id='comment-post-message'>
        <a expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_comment-editor-toggle-link&quot;' href='javascript:void(0)'><data:postCommentMsg/></a></h4>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' frameborder='0' height='410' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' style='display: none' width='200px'/>
    <b:else/>
      <h4 id='comment-post-message'/>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' frameborder='0' height='410' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' width='830px'/>
    </b:if>
    <data:post.friendConnectJs/>
    <data:post.cmtfpIframe/>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      BLOG_CMT_createIframe(&#39;<data:post.appRpcRelayPath/>&#39;, &#39;<data:post.communityId/>&#39;);
    </script>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='threaded_comments' var='post'>
  <div class='comments' id='comments'>
    <a name='comments'/>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 0'><div class='head'>Then leave the first comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 1'><div class='head'>Then be the second commenter!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 2'><div class='head'>Then write the third comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 3'><div class='head'>Then leave comment #4!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 4'><div class='head'>Then be the fifth to comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 5'><div class='head'>Then leave the sixth comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 6'><div class='head'>Then be #7 to comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 7'><div class='head'>Then write the 8th comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 8'><div class='head'>Then leave the ninth comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments &gt; 8'><div class='head'>Then leave another comment!</div></b:if>


    <div class='comments-content'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.embedCommentForm'>
        <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comment_js'/>
      </b:if>
      <div id='comment-holder'>
         <data:post.commentHtml/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class='comment-footer'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.allowNewComments'>
        <b:include data='post' name='threaded-comment-form'/>
      <b:else/>
        <data:post.noNewCommentsText/>
      </b:if>
    </p>

    <b:if cond='data:showCmtPopup'>
      <div id='comment-popup'>
        <iframe allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0' id='comment-actions' name='comment-actions' scrolling='no'>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <div id='backlinks-container'>
    <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_backlinks-container&quot;'>
       <b:if cond='data:post.showBacklinks'>
         <b:include data='post' name='backlinks'/>
       </b:if>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='backlinkDeleteIcon' var='backlink'>
  <span expr:class='&quot;item-control &quot; + data:backlink.adminClass'>
    <a expr:href='data:backlink.deleteUrl' expr:title='data:top.deleteBacklinkMsg'>
      <img src='//www.blogger.com/img/icon_delete13.gif'/>
    </a>
  </span>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='mobile-nextprev'>
  <div class='blog-pager' id='blog-pager'>
    <b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
      <div class='mobile-link-button' id='blog-pager-newer-link'>
      <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'>&amp;lsaquo;</a>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>
      <div class='mobile-link-button' id='blog-pager-older-link'>
      <a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'>&amp;rsaquo;</a>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <div class='mobile-link-button' id='blog-pager-home-link'>
    <a class='home-link' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:homeMsg/></a>
    </div>

    <div class='mobile-desktop-link'>
      <a class='home-link' expr:href='data:desktopLinkUrl'><data:desktopLinkMsg/></a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class='clear'/>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='mobile-post' var='post'>
  <div class='date-outer'>
    <div class='date-posts'>
      <div class='post-outer'>



        <div class='post hentry uncustomized-post-template' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/BlogPosting'>
          <a expr:name='data:post.id'/>
          <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
            <h3 class='post-title entry-title' itemprop='name'>
              <b:if cond='data:post.link'>
                <a expr:href='data:post.link'><data:post.title/></a>
              <b:else/>
                <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
                  <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:post.url'>
                    <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
                  <b:else/>
                    <data:post.title/>
                  </b:if>
                <b:else/>
                  <data:post.title/>
                </b:if>
              </b:if>
            </h3>
          </b:if>

          <div class='post-header'>
            <div class='post-header-line-1'/>
          </div>

          <div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id' itemprop='articleBody'>
            <data:post.body/>
          </div>

          <div class='post-footer'>
            <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-1'>
              <span class='post-author vcard'>
                <b:if cond='data:top.showAuthor'>
                  <b:if cond='data:post.authorProfileUrl'>
                    <span class='fn'>
                      <a expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl' itemprop='author' rel='author' title='author profile'>
                        <data:post.author/>
                      </a>
                    </span>
                  <b:else/>
                    <span class='fn'><data:post.author/></span>
                  </b:if>
                </b:if>
              </span>

              <span class='post-timestamp'>
                <b:if cond='data:top.showTimestamp'>
                  <data:top.timestampLabel/>
                  <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
                    <a class='timestamp-link' expr:href='data:post.url' itemprop='url' rel='bookmark' title='permanent link'><abbr class='published' expr:title='data:post.timestampISO8601' itemprop='datePublished'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr></a>
                  </b:if>
                </b:if>
              </span>

              <span class='post-comment-link'>
                <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
                  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
                    <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>
                    </b:if>
                  </b:if>
                </b:if>
              </span>
            </div>

            <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-2'>
              <b:if cond='data:top.showMobileShare'>
                <div class='mobile-link-button goog-inline-block' id='mobile-share-button'>
                  <a href='javascript:void(0);'><data:shareMsg/></a>
                </div>
              </b:if>
              <b:if cond='data:top.showDummy'>
                <div class='goog-inline-block dummy-container'><data:post.dummyTag/></div>
              </b:if>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.showThreadedComments'>
            <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
          <b:else/>
            <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.showThreadedComments'>
            <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
          <b:else/>
            <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='postQuickEdit' var='post'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.editUrl'>
    <span expr:class='&quot;item-control &quot; + data:post.adminClass'>
      <a expr:href='data:post.editUrl' expr:title='data:top.editPostMsg'>
        <img alt='' class='icon-action' height='18' src='http://img2.blogblog.com/img/icon18_edit_allbkg.gif' width='18'/>
      </a>
    </span>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='main' var='top'>
  <b:if cond='data:mobile == &quot;false&quot;'>

    <!-- posts -->
    <div class='blog-posts hfeed'>

      <b:include data='top' name='status-message'/>

      <data:defaultAdStart/>
      <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>

        <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart'>
          &lt;div class=&quot;date-posts&quot;&gt;
        </b:if>
        <div class='post-outer'>
        <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.showThreadedComments'>
            <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
          <b:else/>
            <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.showThreadedComments'>
            <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
          <b:else/>
            <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
        </div>
        <b:if cond='data:post.includeAd'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>
            <data:defaultAdEnd/>
          <b:else/>
            <data:adEnd/>
          </b:if>
          <div class='inline-ad'>
            <data:adCode/>
          </div>
          <data:adStart/>
        </b:if>
      </b:loop>
      <b:if cond='data:numPosts != 0'>
        &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
      </b:if>
      <data:adEnd/>
    </div>

    <!-- navigation -->
    <b:include name='nextprev'/>

    <!-- feed links -->
    <b:include name='feedLinks'/>

    <b:if cond='data:top.showStars'>
      <script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'/>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load(&quot;annotations&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, {&quot;locale&quot;: &quot;<data:top.languageCode/>&quot;});
        function initialize() {
          google.annotations.setApplicationId(<data:top.blogspotReviews/>);
          google.annotations.createAll();
          google.annotations.fetch();
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
      </script>
    </b:if>

  <b:else/>
    <b:include name='mobile-main'/>
  </b:if>

  <b:if cond='data:top.showDummy'>
    <data:top.dummyBootstrap/>
  </b:if>

</b:includable>
<b:includable id='commentDeleteIcon' var='comment'>
  <span expr:class='&quot;item-control &quot; + data:comment.adminClass'>
    <b:if cond='data:showCmtPopup'>
      <div class='goog-toggle-button'>
        <div class='goog-inline-block comment-action-icon'/>
      </div>
    <b:else/>
      <a class='comment-delete' expr:href='data:comment.deleteUrl' expr:title='data:top.deleteCommentMsg'>
        <img src='//www.blogger.com/img/icon_delete13.gif'/>
      </a>
    </b:if>
  </span>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='feedLinks'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'> <!-- Blog feed links -->
    <b:if cond='data:feedLinks'>
      <div class='blog-feeds'>
        <b:include data='feedLinks' name='feedLinksBody'/>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <b:else/> <!--Post feed links -->
    <div class='post-feeds'>
      <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.feedLinks'>
            <b:include data='post.feedLinks' name='feedLinksBody'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
      </b:loop>
    </div>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='threaded-comment-form' var='post'>
  <div class='comment-form'>
    <a name='comment-form'/>
    <b:if cond='data:mobile'>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' frameborder='0' height='410' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' style='display: none' width='200px'/>
    <b:else/>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' frameborder='0' height='410' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' style='margin:0 0 0 48px' width='675px'/>
    </b:if>
    <data:post.friendConnectJs/>
    <data:post.cmtfpIframe/>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      BLOG_CMT_createIframe(&#39;<data:post.appRpcRelayPath/>&#39;, &#39;<data:post.communityId/>&#39;);
    </script>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='mobile-index-post' var='post'>
  <div class='mobile-date-outer date-outer'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
      <div class='date-header'>
        <span><data:post.dateHeader/></span>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <div class='mobile-post-outer'>
      <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
        <h3 class='mobile-index-title entry-title' itemprop='name'>
          <data:post.title/>
        </h3>

        <div class='mobile-index-arrow'>&amp;rsaquo;</div>

        <div class='mobile-index-contents'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
            <div class='mobile-index-thumbnail'>
              <div class='Image'>
                <img expr:src='data:post.thumbnailUrl'/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </b:if>

          <div class='post-body'>
            <b:if cond='data:post.snippet'><data:post.snippet/></b:if>
          </div>
        </div>

      </a>

      <div class='mobile-index-comment'>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>
            <b:if cond='data:post.numComments != 0'>
              <a class='comment-link' expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' expr:onclick='data:post.addCommentOnclick'>
                <data:post.commentLabelFull/>:
              </a>
            </b:if>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='iframe_comments' var='post'>

  <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>
    <script expr:src='data:post.commentSrc' type='text/javascript'/>
    <div class='cmt_iframe_holder'/>

    <b:if cond='data:post.embedCommentForm == &quot;false&quot;'>
      <a expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' expr:onclick='data:post.addCommentOnclick'><data:postCommentMsg/></a>
    </b:if>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='feedLinksBody' var='links'>
  <div class='feed-links'>
  <data:feedLinksMsg/>
  <b:loop values='data:links' var='f'>
     <a class='feed-link' expr:href='data:f.url' expr:type='data:f.mimeType' target='_blank'><data:f.name/> (<data:f.feedType/>)</a>
  </b:loop>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='comments' var='post'>
  <div class='comments' id='comments'>
    <a name='comments'/>
    <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>



<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 0'><div class='head'>Then leave the first comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 1'><div class='head'>Then be the second commenter!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 2'><div class='head'>Then write the third comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 3'><div class='head'>Then leave comment #4!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 4'><div class='head'>Then be the fifth to comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 5'><div class='head'>Then leave the sixth comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 6'><div class='head'>Then be #7 to comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 7'><div class='head'>Then write the 8th comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 8'><div class='head'>Then leave the ninth comment!</div></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:post.numComments &gt; 8'><div class='head'>Then leave another comment!</div></b:if>



      <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_comments-block-wrapper&quot;'>
        <dl expr:class='data:post.avatarIndentClass' id='comments-block'>

          <b:loop values='data:post.comments' var='comment'>
            <dt expr:class='&quot;comment-author &quot; + data:comment.authorClass' expr:id='data:comment.anchorName'>
              <b:if cond='data:comment.favicon'>
                <img expr:src='data:comment.favicon' height='16px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;' width='16px'/>
              </b:if>
              <a expr:name='data:comment.anchorName'/>
              <b:if cond='data:blog.enabledCommentProfileImages'>
                <data:comment.authorAvatarImage/>
              </b:if>
              <b:if cond='data:comment.authorUrl'>
                <a expr:href='data:comment.authorUrl' rel='nofollow'><data:comment.author/></a>
              <b:else/>
                <data:comment.author/>
              </b:if>
              just had to say...
            </dt>
            <dd class='comment-body' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + data:comment.cmtBodyIdPostfix'>
              <b:if cond='data:comment.isDeleted'>
                <span class='deleted-comment'><data:comment.body/></span>
              <b:else/>
                <p>
<span class='comment-timestamp'>
                <a expr:href='data:comment.url' title='comment permalink'>
                  <data:comment.timestamp/>
                </a>
                <b:include data='comment' name='commentDeleteIcon'/>
              </span>

                  <data:comment.body/>
                </p>
              </b:if>
            </dd>
            <dd class='comment-footer'>

            </dd>
          </b:loop>
        </dl>
      </div>

      <b:if cond='data:post.commentPagingRequired'>
        <span class='paging-control-container'>
          <a expr:class='data:post.oldLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.oldestLinkUrl'>
            <data:post.oldestLinkText/>
          </a>
          <a expr:class='data:post.oldLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.olderLinkUrl'>
            <data:post.olderLinkText/>
          </a>
          <data:post.commentRangeText/>
          <a expr:class='data:post.newLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.newerLinkUrl'>
            <data:post.newerLinkText/>
          </a>
          <a expr:class='data:post.newLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.newestLinkUrl'>
            <data:post.newestLinkText/>
          </a>
        </span>
      </b:if>

      <p class='comment-footer'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.embedCommentForm'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.allowNewComments'>
            <b:include data='post' name='comment-form'/>
          <b:else/>
            <data:post.noNewCommentsText/>
          </b:if>
        <b:else/>
          <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>
            <a expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' expr:onclick='data:post.addCommentOnclick'><data:postCommentMsg/></a>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>

      </p>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:showCmtPopup'>
      <div id='comment-popup'>
        <iframe allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0' id='comment-actions' name='comment-actions' scrolling='no'>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <div id='backlinks-container'>
    <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_backlinks-container&quot;'>
       <b:if cond='data:post.showBacklinks'>
         <b:include data='post' name='backlinks'/>
       </b:if>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:includable>
</b:widget>
</b:section>
      </div> 




      <!-- spacer for skins that want sidebar and main to be the same height-->
      <div class='clear'>&#160;</div>

    </div> <!-- end content-wrapper -->

 <!-- end outer-wrapper --> 

    </div>

<div id='footer-wrapper'>

      <b:section class='footer' id='footer'>
<b:widget id='HTML3' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'>
<b:includable id='main'>
  <!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
    <h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
  </b:if>
  <div class='widget-content'>
    <data:content/>
  </div>

  <b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:includable>
</b:widget>
</b:section>

</div>




  <b:include data='blog' name='google-analytics'/>







</body>
```

Comment: Maybe because it *is* inside the main element. Did/can you edit the HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have moved the footer, editing the html, outside of everything.  And it shows up outside, on post pages.  But on the home page it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi now replace your footer

```
<div id="main-wrapper"></div>
than this
<div id="footer-wrapper"></div>
```

as like this

your code is  this

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
<div id="main" class="main section">
<div id="footer-wrapper">  // remove this code here 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
<script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="//www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/3809499334-widgets.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
</div>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div id="footer-wrapper">  // add here footer code in your html
```

now

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I have tried to change it.  I'm sorry, I still don't understand your suggestion.  On my post pages the footer is outside the outer-wrapper, but on the homepage it moves inside the main-wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the response again, but I don't have "main section" in my css.  I don't know the correct terminology, but blogger doesn't allow its users access to all of the css necessarily.  I can move the main-wrapper, and the sidebar and footer.  And the footer is _definitely_ already outside the outer wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Check this structure of code. Specially footer div.

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="crosscol-wrapper" style="text-align:center">//your code</div>
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">//your code</div>
  <div id="main-wrapper">//your code</div>
  <div id="footer-wrapper">//your code</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I essentially have that structure.  Blogger wraps elements in a few extra (redundant) elements for some reason, ie the crosscol-wrapper contains the outer and main wrappers, but surely it shouldn't get in the way?